# Getting return value of a function called with assembly

Tags: c++, function, assembly, return-value, call

I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010.

If I have a function like this:

```
const char* blah(void);
```

and I want to call it like this:

```
__asm {
    call blah;
    ...
}
```

How do I get the return value of the function in the assembly?

Comment: If you have to ask this question, the answer should probably be: you don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value is in the EAX register.

Comment: Always on that register? Or there are exceptions or something? (Could you put some source?)

Answer (score 1):

See for instance http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2b2ssfy(VS.80).aspx.

Comment: That doesn't help me know what asm instructions to use to get the return value.

Comment: What are you looking for that isn't **the differences between the calling conventions, how arguments are passed, and how values are returned by functions**.